# How should i use atexit in python?

Tags: python-3.x, atexit

I use this code below but it only outputs a "TypeError: the first argument must be callable"

```
import atexit

def end_script():
    print("ahh yes it works")

atexit.register(end_script())

while True:
    print("It still doesn't work")
```

Shouldn't atexit.register(x) just call x when the script closes?
All the reference I got is confusing so I'm kinda lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *called* `end_script` and passed its return value to `register`. Don't call it, just do:

```
atexit.register(end_script)  # No call parens after end_script
```